# Executing java methods and application on remote slave

Tags: java, reflection, rmi, processbuilder

I want to able to have a client/server application which can perform the following:

1. Have client send "java task instructions" (ex. name of method, class to run or app to execute) to a remote server
2. server receives the task execution details and launches a new JVM and loads the classpath etc...
3. server executes the task
4. server stores the task response in a cache
5. shuts down the new JVM
6. server continues to wait for further executable task details which could reference object in cache by name

What is the best APIs to implement this in Java if I don't want to use RMI? 
Do I want to establish a connection by using a socket or is there an easier API?

From what I know, correct me if im wrong, I cannot use ProcessBuilder to execute a static method or to get a response.

thanks in advance

***UPDATE***

I am new to threads and RMI, so how would I then make it so that when client gets the factory stub to creates a new object which will contain the behavior actually needed to execute a task on the server, that the object code is executing in its own thread?

I want this behavior so that two different clients are executing two different tasks at the same time in different threads without reusing the same remote object instance. Here is some simple sample code to help explain what I want

Factor Interface

```
public interface Factory extends Remote
{
    public Executor create() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Factory implementation

```
public class FactoryImpl implements Factory
{
    public FactoryImpl()
    {}

    @Override
    public Executor create() throws RemoteException
    {
         //create a new executor in another thread
    }
}
```

Executor interface

```
public interface Executor extends Runnable, Remote
{
    public String executeTask(String pClass, String pMethod, List<String> arguments) throws RemoteException;

}
```

Do I just want to create/start a new Runnable class that instantiates the executor object?

Comment: In number two you're prescribing a specific behavior "launches a new JVM". I doubt this is actually part of your requirements. You may be wanting to launch a thread to execute a task. In any case, you are probably looking for a Java application server.

Comment: What you have decribed is met 100% by RMI Activation, but I agree with @gknicker that you may not really need to do all this.

Comment: looks like RMI is the right way to go. thanks